# CORS localhost ajax request

Tags: ajax

I have an HTML page (`http://localhost:8888/test/test.html`) in which I'm trying to pull data from a Drupal 7 website.

I'm using this AJAX code with HTML-Request. I have tried JSON and the website prevents me from pulling, even I have added the following code to pull the data.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

This is the HTML page that requests AJAX from Drupal 7 website. Could you please check it for me?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        // The link we are accessing.
        url: "http://horizon-websolutions.com",
        // The type of request.
        type: "get",
        // The type of data that is getting returned.
        dataType: "html",
        error: function () {
          alert("error");
          // Load the content in to the page.
          $("#output").html("<p>Page Not Found!!</p>");
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
          alert("not yet");
        },
        complete: function () {
          alert("done");
        },
        success: function (strData) {
          alert("success");
          // Load the content in to the page.
          $("#output").html(strData);
        }
      });
      // Prevent default click.
      return(false);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Please help me telling the website to accept my localhost request to pull data from the server. I have tested the same code on a pure PHP page and it is working fine.

Comment: What actual error are you getting?  Do you see the CORS header in the actual response?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap you javascript to user `$` for `jQuery`, since it does not automatically refer to `jQuery` in Drupal 7. Try like that:

```
(function ($) {
  // Your code here
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Reference: [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722#using-jquery)

Comment: i have tried your way dear , but with no resutl

Comment: i have updated the whole code , could you please check it for me ? just add it in an html page an check it , :(

Comment: I can check it first this evening, since I got to work now. Hope you solve your problem till then.

Comment: You need to provide more info, where do you put this script in Drupal, what errors you get, etc.

Comment: no dear , this code is placed in an html page . that connect to a drupal page to pull data , this is it , no more info needed

Comment: Ok, I got it completely wrong at first. Thought your AJAX call is in Drupal and you need to pull data from another webpage outside of Drupal. In that case, I'm not really sure if this question is about Drupal and fits here.

Comment: It might still be about Drupal, it depends...@MohammadMoussa I just want to check, you do know that you need to set the access control header in the _Drupal_ site, not the other site?

Comment: no dear , 
1)this front page 
http://horizon-websolutions.com
is for drupal website 

2) the code that i have added above is for html page

i want to pull data from drupal front page to html page using ajax 

drupal front page  --> html page

im trying to add header(cross-origin).....

but its not working 

thank you for your help